# bootstrap navbar doesn't set li to active on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building my first website using HTML/CSS/Bootstrap, and I decided to use scrollspy + affix for my navbar. I realized some problems with it in these scenarios:

1) On first entering the site, when you don't scroll, and then click on any of the nav items right away, the item doesn't become active until after you click on a different one or if you scroll a little no matter how many times you click it

2) Without scrolling again after refreshing the page, if you click 'about me' and then 'resume' the 'about me' becomes active. Clicking any of the following buttons will result in the previous one becoming active instead.

After clicking around or scrolling, it works normally, but otherwise won't.

I'm not sure if it has to do with wonky margins/padding, or poor implementation. Any help is really appreciated. thanks! (fiddle below)

Comment: here's the jsfiddle (some css elements didn't translate over, sorry for the poor contrast on hover items): https://jsfiddle.net/a97s1mnr/1/

please view it without the collapsed navbar :)

Comment: The jsfiddle seems to be working just fine on my machine. When scrolling down to about me, the active css works as expected. What browser are you using? I'm on chrome.

Comment: @arlyon I'm also on Chrome-- The problem lies in when you don't scroll at all because the li elements don't become active (you can see it through inspecting + the background of it doesn't become black), it kind of just stays on the hover state/acts like you didn't click it at all.


thanks for taking the time to look :)

Comment: I see. Have a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2816bs6c/5/ I removed the page loading script and scroll and it works now.

Comment: @arlyon Thanks! It does work. Do you know why it was affecting the navbar? and if possible do you know how I could put in a page loading script without affecting it?

Comment: Just kidding, I figured it out, it had something to do with the webkit for animatebottom. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Didn't see your last comment until now. Glad you got it working.